How to create an escape hatch in swift's Encodable
I'm looking for a way to create an escape hatch in Encodable. There are many JSON APIs that are more flexible than Encodable allows for. As an example, take the Anthropic API which allows you to specify a JSON schema as part of the request body. This schema is not known ahead of time to the programmer, as the end user can craft it. See the input_schema field here: https://docs.anthropic.com/en/docs/build-with-claude/tool-use
My goal is to enforce a strict contract where it makes sense (fixed fields) and allow
for an escape hatch of [String: Any] when the structure if flexible. These aims are hard to achieve. I have been working on it for two days, writing various encoder hacks trying to get the desired output. What I have found is that it's trivial to stay fully in the untyped world or fully in the strict contract world:
This is very flexible, and works out of the box:
let myTree: [String: Any] = [
    "a": "xyz",
    "b": [
        "c": 2,
        "d": false
    ]
]

do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myTree)
    print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
    print("Could not convert flexible dictionary to JSON: \(error)")
}

This is very rigid, and works out of the box:
struct Root: Encodable {
    let a: String
    let b: Child
}

struct Child: Encodable {
    let c: Int
    let d: Bool
}

let myTree = Root(a: "xyz", b: Child(c: 2, d: false))

do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .sortedKeys
    let data = try encoder.encode(myTree)
    print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
    print("Could not convert encodable struct to JSON: \(error)")
}

If you run both of those, you'll see that the two print statements produce the same JSON, great! Now assume that the structure of field b isn't known ahead of time, e.g. in the case of an API where the user specifies the schema. I want to do this:
struct RootWithEscapeHatch: Encodable {
    let a: String
    let b: [String: Any]

    private enum Fields: CodingKey {
        case a
        case b
    }

    func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Fields.self)
        try container.encode(self.a, forKey: .a)
        // try container.encode(self.b, forKey: .b)  <-- What goes here?
    }
}


let myFailingTree = RootWithEscapeHatch(a: "xyz", b: ["c": 2, "d": false])
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(myFailingTree)
    print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
    print("Could not convert encodable with escape hatch to JSON: \(error)")
}

You can see that myFailingTree is isomorphic with myTree examples above. I want the print statements to produce the same JSON. If you have an idea for what goes in the "What goes here?" line, please let me know. I'm looking for a general solution, I.e. I don't want to hard code that the structure will always be ["c": 2, "d": false]. The point is that any [String: Any] field should be serializable just like the first example in this question.
Thanks!

(En)codable does not support Any.

You can indeed compel encodable to support Any. I've done it here, in a hacky proof of concept. I want to see if someone out there has a robust method for accomplishing the same goal: https://zell-public.s3.amazonaws.com/encodable_escape_passing_tests.png

If the question is only about encoding, what is wrong with JSONSerialization? From performance perspective writing a lot of boilerplate code to compel encodable to support Any is a kind of fighting the framework.

There is nothing wrong with JSONSerialization. I was hoping that there was an Apple-blessed way to combine Encodable with something as flexible as JSONSerialization for a single field. E.g. I want most of the contract to be strict (using encodable) but one field in the contract should be extremely flexible, and thus have a [String: Any] type. I have abandoned all type gymnastics with codable, as you can see in my answer it's convoluted and only correct for a subset of cases.

Update: I'm now using the solution by @xAlien95 , which I've marked as the answer to this question

You can use a custom JSONValue type instead of [String: Any]:
enum JSONValue {
  case none
  case bool(Bool)
  case int(Int)
  case double(Double)
  case string(String)
  indirect case array([JSONValue])
  indirect case object([String: JSONValue])
}

make it Encodable:
extension JSONValue: Encodable {
  private struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init(stringValue: String) {
      self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? = nil
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    switch self {
    case .none:
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encodeNil()
    case .bool(let value):
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(value)
    case .int(let value):
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(value)
    case .double(let value):
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(value)
    case .string(let value):
      var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
      try container.encode(value)
    case .array(let values):
      var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
      for value in values { try container.encode(value) }
    case .object(let dictionary):
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      for (key, value) in dictionary {
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .init(stringValue: key))
      }
    }
  }
}

and, optionally, easier to type by conforming it to the various ExpressibleBy…Literal protocols:
extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
  init(nilLiteral: ()) {
    self = .none
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
  init(booleanLiteral value: BooleanLiteralType) {
    self = .bool(value)
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
  init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
    self = .int(value)
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
  init(floatLiteral value: FloatLiteralType) {
    self = .double(value)
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
  init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
    self = .string(value)
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
  init(arrayLiteral elements: JSONValue...) {
    self = .array(elements)
  }
}

extension JSONValue: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
  init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, JSONValue)...) {
    self = .object(.init(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements))
  }
}

With JSONValue you can then get what you're looking for as follows:
struct RootWithEscapeHatch: Encodable {
  let a: String
  let b: JSONValue
}

let tree = RootWithEscapeHatch(a: "xyz", b: ["c": 2, "d": false])
try print(String(data: JSONEncoder().encode(tree), encoding: .utf8)!)

It is more generale than providing [String: Any] since you now can place anything as JSONValue, e.g. nil, scalar types or eterogeneous arrays.

Oooh, that's pretty slick!

 Experimental solution:

⚠️ I don't recommend this in production but it may help you come up with an idea :)

Use JSONSerialization to encode the dictionary to a json string.
func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Fields.self)
    try container.encode(self.a, forKey: .a)
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: b)
    try container.encode(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), forKey: .b)
}

This will cause the b value to be escaped again! So remove the escaping from the result (not like this):
print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self).replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\"", with: "\""))

Result:
{"b":"{"c":2,"d":false}","a":"xyz"}


 Path to the redemption:
There are only 2 situations:

You know the schema -> Use Encoder
You don't know the schema -> Use Serializer

So maybe you needed something like the following pseudo code:
func encodedData() throws -> Data {
  return switch wrappedValue {
  case let .knownSchema(myWellKnownObject): try JSONEncoder().encode(myWellKnownObject)
  case let .unknownSchema(myUnknownObject): try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myUnknownObject)
  }
}

I hope this gives you some idea

I hadn't considered your top approach! I don't mind it, warnings and all :)
Your summary also makes a lot of sense. I am trying to fight it. It's a bit of a special case that part of the API is pre-defined with a schema and the other part isn't. Maybe for those cases I can fall back to the serializer for the entire tree. In any case, thanks for your input!
